# Scoket in newtwork and programming

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

first question : is the socket API between the application layer and transport layer in network models is the same as the one used in programming ?

second question : if socket API is interface between application layer and transprot layer is that mean that any application layer must use it to communicate with transport layer ?. (http, SMTP, FTP...)

Answer (score 0):

in my view, these two questions are actually one question : how OSI or TCP/IP module works.

When prgramming apps, we use TCP/UDP user space APIs, and we don't need to care about how kernel run it. You can say we use it in application layer(app), but these APIs are working in transport layer. For example, we use socket/bind/connect/accept/listen in user spaces, and the OS will use system call to run it in kernel, following from transport layer -> network layer -> Data link layer -> Network card and go out/in.

So, there is not so-called same thing programming between application layer and transport layer (unless you are a kernel developer), it's yes that HTTP/FTP must use these APIs to connect to other network clients/servers. But your declaration may need to edit for they may make yourself confused.

Comment: I'm a little confused why there is no reply. If you have any problem of the answer, please tell me so that we can improve it. If it's helpful to you, can you please give me a useful upvote or acception? That's important for me.